# App Engine: Does put(java.lang.Iterable<Entity> entities) reduce the number of write operations?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Does calling the `put(java.lang.Iterable<Entity> entities)` which performs a batch put of the list of entities reduces the number of datastore write operations to just **one** as compared to calling `put(Entity entity)` n number of times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not affect the write operations. As described at [Billable Resource Unit Costs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing#Billable_Resource_Unit_Costs) in the App Engine documentation, the write operations count per entity that is stored in the datastore.

What makes a difference is the total time needed to perform all operations as in batch operations the response time from datastore is minimized compared to a series of standalone opoerations.

Hope this helps!